# trying to import mlab from the enthought mayavi module - getting " RuntimeError: No pyface.toolkits plugin could be loaded for qt4"

Tags: enthought

## The program starts with:-

```
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.tools import visual
```

## and ends up with this message

```
>/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/lib/python3.5/si>te->packages/pyface/base_toolkit.py in import_toolkit(toolkit_name, >entry_point)
>    225     msg = msg.format(entry_point, toolkit_name)
>    226     logger.info(msg)
>--> 227     raise RuntimeError(msg)
>RuntimeError: No pyface.toolkits plugin could be loaded for qt4
```

Comment: There are a fair number of hits on the web for that message. What research have you done? Also, people here are going to want to see code or build scripts that can be used to repro the problem. Since this looks environmental, you aren't going to get much traction here is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

For licensing reasons, Canopy for Python 3.x does not ship with PyQt. Please install PyQt from the Canopy Package Manager, then try again. For more information, search the Enthought Knowledge base for `pyqt python 3`, which will give you a link to this article: ["Python 3 in Canopy 2 - 'No module named PyQt4' error"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001655566).